# Laravel 8: Call to undefined method Model::contains()

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I'm using Laravel 8 for my project and in this project and I have created a custom Middleware called `Admin` that goes like this:

```
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
{
    if (Auth::user()->isAdmin()) {
        return $next($request);
    }

    return redirect('/');
}
```

And I tried applying it like this:

```
Route::middleware('admin')->group(function () {
   Route::get('test', function () { return "User is authenticated and is an admin."; });
});
```

And on `Kernel.php` at `$middlewareGroups` section:

```
'admin' => [
   'auth',
   \App\Http\Middleware\Admin::class
],
```

So I called the `isAdmin()` at User Model which simply checks if the role of the user is correct or not:

```
public function role()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Role::class);
}

public function isAdmin()
{
    return $this->role->contains('slug', 'super-admin');
}
```

But now the problem is, when I go to `/test` uri, it does not redirect me to `('/')` uri and shows me this error:

**BadMethodCallException
Call to undefined method App\Models\Role::contains()**

So what is going wrong here? How can I fix this issue?

Note that the relationship between `roles` and `users` table is One To Many. That's why I wrote `role()` instead of `roles()` because each user has only one role.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use a `belongsTo` relationship, laravel will return the model directly and not a collection of models.

When you call:

```
$this->role
```

What you get is either null (if the relationship does not exist) or a `Role` model. You can write your `isAdmin` function accordingly:

```php
public function isAdmin()
{
    return empty($this->role) ? false : $this->role->slug === 'super-admin';
}
```

You probably copied the code from an example with a Many to many relationship: in that case Laravel will return a collection of models and you can invoke [collection methods](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#available-methods) on it, such as `contains`

Answer (score 0):

could we see a snip of your Role Model.